# I'm trying to combine PDO and OOP, and can't get it to work

Tags: php, mysql, security, oop, pdo

So I basically have two files. At the end I would have more, but I would like to create a class called `DB` that would use PDO database operations, and then I would extend this class to make all of my functions for working with the database. So `DB` class, would then extend to class `dbADD`, that would have all the add functions for different database tables.

This is called `config.php`:

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DBHOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DBUSER', 'REMOVED');
DEFINE ('DBPSW', 'REMOVED');
DEFINE ('DBNAME', 'REMOVED');

class DB {
    public $db;
    private static $instance;   

    public function __constructor(){
        $config ['db'] = array(
        'host'      =>  DBHOST,
        'username'  =>  DBUSER,
        'password'  =>  DBPSW,
        'dbname'    =>  DBNAME,
        );

        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host ='  . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname='  .   $config['db']['dbname'],$config['db']['username'],$config['db']['password']) ;
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function GetArticles ($search){
        $sql = "SELECT `FirstColumn`, `SrcColumn`, `article` FROM `test_table`  WHERE `FirstColumn` = 23";  

        //$dbs = new DB();
        $dbs = DB::getInstance();
        $query = $dbs->db->prepare($sql);
        //$query->bindValue(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            // = $row['article'],'</br>';
            $return = $row['article'];
        }   
        return $return;
    }
}
?>
```

This file is my test file, which is not that important just a testing-ground. Called `test.php`:

```
<?php
require_once('app_core/config.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $db = new DB();
    //echo $db->db;
    //echo $db->GetTestDB();
    //$test = $db->TestThis();
    //print_r($test);
    echo $db->GetArticles('23');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

If it is possible I also have two other concerns: the first question is a matter of securit -- is this a good practice or not? The other question is how do I hide files with this password data, so I can use them but no one can read them?

Comment: What you think is OOP is not OOP. OOP isn't just throwing together some classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you've got a lot going on here, so I'll try to address issues one at a time to make this class behave properly and in an object-oriented manner (instead of a collection of not-entirely-related methods).

#### First, your constructor:

```
//  Make these private, will find out why in a moment...
private $db;
// __construct, not __constructor!!
private function __construct() {
    // This whole array doesn't serve any purpose because the constants
    // are defined and available in all scopes
    // while this array is local to the __construct().  
    // Just get rid of it and use the 
    // constants directly in the PDO connection
    //$config ['db'] = array(
    //    'host'          =>      DBHOST,
    //    'username'      =>      DBUSER,
    //    'password'      =>      DBPSW,
    //    'dbname'        =>      DBNAME,
    //);

    // Use some error checking when establishing your connection
    try {
      // Some extra bad whitespace removed around =
      $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPSW); 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

#### Next your singleton accessor getInstance().

```
// No code changes necessary....
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
    {
        $object = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $object;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Since you have defined a method to access the class as a singleton, the `$db` property and the `__construct()` are made `private`.  At no point will you ever call `$DB_class-instance = new DB()` to instantiate it, or call `$DB_class_instance->db` to access the connection directly.  Instead, you will call `DB::getInstance()` to access the singleton instance and your methods like `GetArticles()` to execute queries.

#### Now onto your querying method:

```
public function GetArticles ($search){
    // Ok a SQL string, no problem...
    $sql = "SELECT `FirstColumn`, `SrcColumn`, `article` FROM `test_table`  WHERE `FirstColumn` = :search";

    // There's no need for this.  You already defined $db as 
    // a class property, so you should be using $this->db
    // $dbs = DB::getInstance();

    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    // bind the $search input parameter...
    $query->bindParam(':search', $search);

    // Test for success
    if ($query->execute()) {

      $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) {
      // I suppose you know what you want here. If you're only expecting 
      // one article, there's no real need for the while loop.
      // You can just fetch() once.
      $return = $row->article;

      // OR.....

      // However, if you are expecting *multiple* rows, you should be accumulating them
      // into an array like this:
      $return = array();
      while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
         // Append to an array
         $return[] = $row->article;
         // OR to get multiple columns returned as an object...
         $return[] = $row;
      }
      return $return;
   }
   else {
     // Query failed, return false or something
     return FALSE;
   }
}
```

#### Finally your controller code:

```
// The constructor is private, so you can't do this
// $db = new DB();
// Instead you need to use getInstance()
$db = DB::getInstance();
// Returns an array, so print_r()
print_r($db->GetArticles('23'));
```

Since we made the class' `$db` property `private`, it cannot be accessed outside the class. Therefore you would need to define querying methods similar to `GetArticles()` for any other queries you plan to run as well.  If you think you will need to build ad-hoc queries that are not class methods sometimes, then you can change it to

```
public $db
```

Then, you could do things outside the class like the following instead of having to build a class method to do it. You *do* still need to call `getInstance()` however.

```
$dbs = DB::getInstance();
// Run a query via the PDO connection $dbs->db
$result = $dbs->db->query('SELECT * FROM sometable');
```

#### Little style issue:

This won't actually cause a problem since identifiers are case-insensitive, but stylistically it is weird. `define()` is a function call and is usually used lowercase:

```
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'REMOVED');
define('DBPSW', 'REMOVED');
define('DBNAME', 'REMOVED');
```

#### About your file security

As long as your web server is correctly configured, no one else can read the files. Provided the web server sends .php files to the PHP interpreter rather than dumping their contents to the browser, the files are safe. If you are on a shared host and the host does not properly segregate your files from other tenants, that is their problem and the only good solution would be to get a better host.

It is wise, however, to store your sensitive files above your web server's document root directory. Then even a misconfigured web server could not accidentally dump their contents to a client. They are only accessible to PHP via `include`.

Comment: I will delete it :D Sorry i did not know, where is the are for elaboration on the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, im very grateful. Im new to this site but i like it very much.

Comment: @MrNewbProgrammer Happy to help. For future reference, a lot of the time, a question this large in scope won't get a good response and may be immediately closed by the community as too broad. It is best to tackle small issues one at a time, but the sequence here lays out well enough that I could address them to build it up into working order.

Comment: LOL - really, downvoter?  Show up 2 days later and downvote without comment?

Comment: What? I dont understand what u mean?

Comment: @MrNewbProgrammer Not directed at you.  Someone downvoted this answer, which I have to say, is about as thorough and detailed as you're ever going to find on SO, but left no comment indicating why.

Comment: Haters gonna hate :D Im very satisfied with the answer, u really did make a good effort and my app is now working exactly as I desired. So tnx :D

Answer (score 2):

As PDO is already an object, maybe you don't need to create a singleton class for it at all.

Instead, make a generic model class which you pass the PDO object to.

```
<?php

class Model {
    private $pdo;

    __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo
    }

    // generic model methods go here
}
```

Then you can subclass this and flesh out the functionality for each model that you create.

Usage would be something like:

```
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host={DBHOST};dbname={DBNAME}", DBUSER, DBPSW);
$myModel = new MyModel($pdo);
$bob = $myModel->getByName('bob');
$articles = new Articles($pdo);
$recentArticles = $articles->getRecent(new Date());
```

In regards to security, this article offers some nice general tips, http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/17/0/0.  In fact, the entire guide is quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Advices:

1. If possible, don't use inline SQL, because if you change the scheme of your database, let's say you rename a column from foo to bar, you will have to find all the inline SQLs where foo is used and change that to bar.
2. Your idea is good, to have a general behavior for different action types, but there is no point of implementing it, because this good idea was implemented before. For instance you can try out Flourish, which is an ORM and can help you a lot.
3. Don't store passwords in separate files if you can store them in databases, but don't forget to encrypt passwords and to use a salt too to improve the encryption.

Comment: Just wanted to say on the first point: I hear the 'changing the scheme of database' argument a lot, but to be the devil's advocate really how hard is it to do a ctrl+f and replace all that text with another name? I just don't see the justification for an ORM for that one sole thing.

Comment: It might be really hard, because it can be present in different files and different languages. If yout foo column is replaced with bar and you have used the foo column 10000 times, for example and the 'foo' word appears at semantically different strings and is still valid in those strings, then your Ctrl+F approach is inefficient.

Comment: Perhaps, but for argument's sake if you're planning ahead for an ORM you could also plan for making the ctrl+f approach efficient if you ever need to replace `foo` ;)

Comment: There is a large difference between ORM and replacement planning. ORM is dynamic and automatically supports database scheme changes, while you have to pay special attention to all the table and column names in your code to simplify a future name change if you use replacement planning. Sometimes it's justified to not use ORMs, but when you are developing a large system using a large database with many use-cases, it might become very difficult to work without an ORM.

Comment: ORMs are a lesser tool of the coding devil to lure you into an extra dependency.